# Single network interface with multiple IPs

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I'd like to implement multiple VPN protocol tunnels on the same virtual interface.
My VPN tunnel is implemented on top of UDP connection so basically I can use this connection to send packets to different locations according to their source ip address (which represent the packet requested VPN protocol).

I intend to configure the routing table with top priority rules that route connections to 'default' address, originated by one of the IPs I've configured in the interface, will be routed to the virtual interface. For example, here's a possible output from `netstat` command.

```
default            10.21.11.56        UGScg           utun2 (for protocol 1)
default            10.21.11.57        UGScg           utun2 (for protocol 2)
```

On the RX side : I catch all packets arrived to the virtual interface, wrap them with the correct vpn protocol header according to their destination and send them over a UDP connection through a physical interface

On the TX side : I read packets from the UDP connection, and according to their destination, decide the packet VPN protocol to use to decapsulate the packet from it's uppermost header.

My question is whether it's possible to set multiple IPs for a single virtual interface. Currently I know to set a single ip using the following ifconfig command :

```
/sbin/ifconfig utun2 10.21.11.56 10.21.11.56 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
```

which create this interface

```
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1400
    inet 10.21.11.56 --> 10.21.11.56 netmask 0xffffffff
```

If i try the ifconfig again to set additional IP address, it simply override the previous ip address.

Thanks !